# Auditing document library (Count how many times user visited it)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to count, How many times a particular user has accessed which document in document library. I want this count to be displayed in a report format. I also want eye (count the number of visit) on which links are being accessed in the site by particular user? Also, need to see if he has clicked any of the external links in the site ? 
How can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just enable Auditing feature and there are all data.